# How to find id of lightning component tag which defined in iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, id, aura-iteration, aura-id

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.List}" var="item" indexVar="i">
                <div id="{!v.globalId + '_option'}" data-index="{!i}" data-id="{!item.Id}" onclick="{!c.jsFunction}"><text-under-div></div>
            </aura:iteration>
```

How can I find the unique id of every div tag which is defined in the iteration on click of div?
I have tried using the following code but not succeed

```
var globalId = component.getGlobalId();
        console.log("globalId:" + globalId);
        var comp = document.getElementById(globalId + '_option');
```

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aura:id, instead:

```
<div aura:id="option" data-index="{!i}" data-id="{!item.Id}" onclick="{!c.jsFunction}"><text-under-div></div>
```

---

```
var options = component.find("option");
options = options? []: options.length? options: [options];
...
```

Comment: ok. means list options contain the global ids of iterating elements...?

Comment: @MohitKumar it'll find the list of elements in your component, which you can then manipulate from there.

Comment: @MohitKumar FYI : We can also use `{!globalId}`  it is unique in every component.so by this way you can also get list of elements in your component , You can go with either this or  @sfdcfox suggested

Comment: @vignesh yes, but, please note, getElementById can only return one value anyways. It is not appropriate for this question's use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{!globalId}` instead of {!v.globalId}.

Component:

`<aura:iteration items="{!v.List}" var="item" indexVar="i">
    <div id="{!globalId + '_option'}" data-index="{!i}" data-id="
        {!item.Id}" onclick="{!c.jsFunction}"><text-under-div></div    </aura:iteration>`

Controller:

```
var globalId = component.getGlobalId();
var divId = globalId + '_option'; 
var elements =  document.querySelectorAll('[Id="'+divId+'"]');
```